# error NG6001: The class 'EaZimmerkatDialogComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

I wanted to create a dialog for my page. After I created the component and started my application it returned two errors:

> **Error: *src/app/app.module.ts:39:5* - error NG6001: The class 'EaZimmerkatDialogComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's de
> clarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.**

and

> **Error: *src/app/dialogs/ea-zimmerkat-dialog/ea-zimmerkat-dialog.component.ts:14:5* - error NG1005: Unexpected decorator inject on parameter.**

I can't explain and find the mistake in the code.

**code** *src/app/app.module.ts*:

```
import {EaZimmerkatDialogComponent} from "./dialogs/ea-zimmerkat-dialog/ea-zimmerkat-dialog.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    AGastComponent,
    AZimmerComponent,
    AZimmerkatComponent,
    EaGastComponent,
    EaZimmerComponent,
    EaZimmerkatComponent,
    GrundgeruestComponent,
    EaZimmerkatDialogComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**code** *src/app/dialogs/ea-zimmerkat-dialog/ea-zimmerkat-dialog.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit, inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef} from "@angular/material/dialog";
import {category} from "../../category";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ea-zimmerkat-dialog',
  templateUrl: './ea-zimmerkat-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ea-zimmerkat-dialog.component.css']
})
export class EaZimmerkatDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EaZimmerkatDialogComponent>,
    @inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: category) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your `EaZimmerkatDialogComponent` where you try to inject the `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` token, you use `@inject` with lowercase `i`. Try replacing that with `@Inject` (with uppercase `I`).

Answer (score 1):

To add onto Octavian Mărculescu's answer, kindly make sure the correct decorator is imported like so:

```
import {Inject} from '@angular/core';
```

Save yourself hours of debugging :)

Comment: Well, supposing that you are using an IDE and not Notepad, the IDE suggests (or directly imports) the symbol for you. There is no debugging to be done, as the app won't compile without this import, so you get a very clear build error when an import is missing.